# When assigning a struct to a variable, is the instance copied or referenced?

Tags: struct, reference, copy, instance

Will this program return true or false?
Will the x value of the struct carry over to a from b?

```
struct Vector(x, y)
{
    public int x, y;
    public Vector(x, y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Main()
{
    Vector a = new Vector(1, 2);
    Vector b = a;
    b.x = 3;
    if (a.x == 3) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: I am stupid, I posted this question because I was at work, I will just test when I get home...

Comment: Can you specify the language, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A structure is essentially equivalent semantically to a bunch of independent variables stuck together with duct tape.  Thus, if one declares

```
public struct Foo {public int X,Y};

Foo f1,f2;
...
f1 = f2;
```

the declaration of f1 and f2 is roughly equivalent to:

```
int f1_X,f1_Y, f2_X,f2_y;
```

and the assignment of f2 to f1 is equivalent to

```
f1_X = f2_X;
f1_Y = f2_Y;
```

Further, defining and calling a method:

```
void Bar(Foo it) {...}
Bar(f1);
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
void Bar(int it_X, int it_Y) {...}
Bar(f1_X,f1_Y);
```

The only aspects of structures which makes `Foo f` really different from `int f_X,f_Y;` are the facts that all of the fields of a structure behave as a unit when a `ref` is passed (e.g. `void Boz(ref Foo it);` will receive one `ref` which identifies both variables, rather than one for each), and an array of a struct type likewise uses one reference for everything, so `var bar = new Foo[12]` would declare one array that holds twelve pairs of integers, whereas `var bar_X = new int[12], bar_Y = new int[12];` would declare a pair of arrays holding twelve integers each.

Although structures can declare helper methods, and one can restrict the ability of outside code to access the struct except via such methods, it is most helpful to think of a struct as simply being a bunch of independent variables stuck together with duct tape.  If that's what one wants, an public-field struct is a perfect fit.  If one wants a type which behaves as something else, one should probably use something else.  The idea that "mutable structs are evil" stems in part from the fact that compilers sometimes do evil things with methods that modify `this`, and in part from the idea that types should be something more than bunches of variables stuck together with duct tape.  It is certainly true that in most types should behave as something other than amalgamations of variables, and such types should be implemented as something other than public-field structures.  That does not mean, however, that in those cases where one does need an amalgamation of independent variables, one should try to use an immutable class to awkwardly emulate such behavior, or a so-called "immutable" struct which tries to emulate the awkward behavior of an immutable class, as opposed to using an exposed-field struct which would, without awkwardness, inherently behave exactly as required.

Comment: Since I was using `Vector`s as an example, you might understand what I'm using them for, acceleration, speed and position in 2D. So I guess I should use `Vector b = a.Clone();`?

Ninjaedit: I mean, I can use this method If I have a bunch of objects in the 2D enviroment which gets a bunch of `Vector`s assigned to them, correct?

Comment: @HolyGarbage: Structures are very good for things like coordinates and vectors, since even when they allow piecewise mutation there's no need to "clone" them.  If one defines structure types for vectors and coordinates, and defines suitable operators for things like `vector+vector->vector`, `vector-vector->vector`, `coordinate+vector->coordinate`, and `coordinate-coordinate->vector`, and `vector*scalar->vector`, then code like `velocity+=acceleration*timestep; position+=velocity*timestep;` will end up being equivalent to...

Comment: ...`velocity_x+=acceleration_x*timestep; velocity_y+=velocity_x*timestep; position_x+=velocity_x*timestep; position_y+=velocity_y*timestep;`.  The C# compiler's "intermediate code" output will end up using a lot of temporary variables, but depending upon the version of the .NET runtime, it may be able to optimize many of them away to yield code similar to the "discrete-variables" form.  If one were using immutable objects for vectors, one would have to create new object instances every step; using mutable objects, one would have to be careful to defensively copying things when needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to carry over, they are the same thing. a and b are pointing to the same object. Whatever changes in one, you can access by the other's reference. So the answer is true.